# Some desktop entry files not working after upgrade to 20.04

Tags: gnome, 20.04, launcher, .desktop

After a relativity smooth upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04.1 I have problems with some desktop entry files in ~/.local/applications.

Most of the desktop entry files are working as expected (e.g., their launchers show when  Show Applications is clicked or their name is entered in the dialog that comes up when  Activities in the upper left corner of the screen is clicked).  But there are a few that don't show.  Some, if I copy them to the Desktop and then click on Allow Launching in the right context menu work while they are on the Desktop, but still don't show in Show Applications or the Activities dialog.  Others don't even get an Allow Launching entry in the context menu.

I have done what I think are all the obvious things---restarting the Gnome Shell, logging out and back in, rebooting both hot and cold. Other strange behaviour includes losing the ability to allow launching from the desktop entry on the Desktop that works after I copy one of the non working desktop entry files from ~/.local/applications that doesn't allow launching onto the Desktop.

Here is one that does get the Allow Launching context menu entry.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.6.5
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name=Math Programs
Name[en_US]=Math Programs
Exec=/home/rquint/.local/bin/MathPrograms
Comment[en_US]=Select a Math Program to run
Comment=Select a Math Program to run
Icon[en_US]=Conic
Icon=Conic
StartupWMClass=QMP
OnlyShowIn=Gnome;
Actions=MaximaDocumentation;SageDocumentation;

[Desktop Action MaximaDocumentation]
Name=Maxima Documentation
Exec=nautilus --no-desktop "/home/rquint/Hardware and Software/Software/Maxima"

[Desktop Action SageDocumentation]
Name=Sage Documentation
Exec=firefox /home/rquint/Sage/SageMath/local/share/doc/sage/html/en/index.html
```

I am also facing another desktop entry files-related problem [Using StartupWMClass for applications running in a terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1279779/using-startupwmclass-for-applications-running-in-a-terminal)