# Using StartupWMClass for applications running in a terminal

Tags: 20.04, launcher, .desktop

In 18.04 I had a launcher in the Dash to run an application in a terminal with the Dash showing an indicator dot for the launcher when it was running, rather than an indicator for the generic terminal launcher (this way I was able to find it if other terminal windows are open). I was able to use the --class option in the Exec entry along with StartupWMClass to achieve this.

In 20.04 the launcher doesn't work in that a terminal is opened, the application tries to launch and then the terminal closes.  I googled this and there is some chatter about the --class option being depreciated.  If I delete the --class option the launcher works, but the indicator dot is attached to the generic terminal launcher.

Here is the .desktop file before deleting the --class option

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Encoding=UTF-8
StartupNotify=true
Icon[en_US]=sage-terminal
Icon=sage-terminal
Exec=/home/rquint/Sage/SageMath/sage --class=SageTerminal
StartupWMClass=SageTerminal
Name=SageTerminal
Name[en_US]=SageTerminal
Actions=SageDocumentation;

[Desktop Action SageDocumentation]
Name=Sage Documentation
Exec=firefox /home/rquint/Sage/SageMath/local/share/doc/sage/html/en/index.html
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a perfect solution, but for now it works.  Googling around I found the following

https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-how-to-make-a-custom-launcher-for-terminal-applications/

which shows how to launch an application in a terminal although the launcher uses Terminal=false. In essense you are launching a terminal emulator which then runs the application.  There are two possible gotchas with this method. First, it specifically calls a particular terminal emulator; second, the --class option is depreciated and may not work in the future.

So, for now (Ubuntu 20.04.1 and Gnome 3.36.3), I have replaced the lines

```
Terminal=true
Exec=/home/rquint/Sage/SageMath/sage --class=SageTerminal
```

with

```
Terminal=false
Exec=gnome-terminal --class=SageTerminal -e /home/rquint/Sage/SageMath/sage
```

and have the behaviour I desired.

Comment: Have you upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04? I'm using the same solution in Jammy but --class option works in xOrg session only whereas in Wayland it's ignored.

Comment: I'm still using 20.04 as my primary machine, but I have set up a Virtual Machine running 22.04 and I have observed the same problem with yad.  There are also some little apps that work fine with Xorg but not under Wayland, e.g., gcolor3.